# Appeal a rejected edit?

Tags: support

I've [attempted to make an edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/78421) to a answer that was factually incorrect, however reviewers have rejected the edit.

Raising another identical edit in the hope that it will get approved by other reviewers doesn't feel like the right way to go about fixing this, so I thought I'd raise the issue here on Meta.

Another [answer here on arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/102555/22078) also backs up my claim.

Comment: We don't edit answers to make them right.  We edit them to make them clearer.  A wrong answer is a downvote action, not an edit one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your edit was rejected because it changes the meaning of the post too much. `False` is totally different than `true`, which you probably know. You should consider downvoting and/or commenting, and maybe post your own, correct answer instead. And you seem to have done at least some of it already.

Comment: Yes, it does change the meaning, I can't argue with that, however I believe the person who wrote the answer meant to use `false` and just got muddled up, so I see it more as 'Correcting a typo'. I've already left a comment, so hopefully the author will spot that and correct it, then I can remove my downvote and comment.

Comment: @Bryan The OP seems active on the site so we should see soon enough.

Comment: @Bryan if you think that the poster made an error in content, then add a comment.  Consider edits on StackOverflow.  If you noticed that someone forgot a comma, edited the post, and the comma turned out to be the entire problem, you have completely altered the environment of the question.

Comment: @3ventic - the answerer does not appear active on the site; isn't that the target you want to edit the answer?

Comment: @JoshDM He posted the answer less than a day ago, and there's a comment on his answer from three hours ago.  I think that's easily within the definition of active.